# Using Future Object in Tornado to execute a file and return a status

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine, concurrent.futures

I am a beginner in tornado and having some difficulties understanding Tornado especially 'Future'. My actual program is to return a status 'Pending' to user without blocking (asynchronous) while a python file is executing in the background. I used 'Subprocess' to run a python script. The python file is to convert a file format. After converting, the program has to update a status to 'Completed' in the MongoDB. Then, return that status to user. Following is my tornado Handler.

```
class FileAsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        res = yield self._work()
        self.write(res)

        client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
        db=client.business
        documents = db.reviews.find({'cuisine':'Fast Food'}).sort('name')
        for document in documents:
                pprint(document)
        print(" <<<<<<<<< Fetched " + str(db.reviews.find({'cuisine':'Fast Food'}).count()) + " >>>>>>>>>>")
        print(" <<<<<<<<< File Executing >>>>>>>>>>")

    @gen.coroutine
    def _work(self):
        cmd = ['python3', '/home/Austin/Desktop/PythonCodes/magician.py']
        p = Subprocess(cmd)
        f = Future()
        p.set_exit_callback(f.set_result)
        return ("Pending")
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What is your question?

Comment: the program is doing returning "Pending", executing file and calling a database all at once. I want to do it one by one. First, update "Pending" status and shows the users while executing a file. After executing a file, it shall update status in database to "Completed" and again show the user